# GridView of Random Colored Cards

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm developing a basic color matching game via Flutter. Rules are easy, depending on the difficulty level chosen by the user, boxes of randomly generated colors are brought to the screen, each of which is placed in a grid form. The color that the user has to click and the remaining time information will be displayed in the upper corner of the screen. After each correct click, all colors in the grid will be reassigned randomly. When the time is over, the score received by the user in the game is shown and the return to the main screen is provided.

But, when I'm trying to reassign the color of cards randomly after tap, it shows me only one color, and nothing changes. How can I solve this?

Screenshot

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MyGame extends StatefulWidget {
  final difficulty;
  final matrix;
  MyGame({Key key, this.difficulty, this.matrix}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyGameState createState() =>
      _MyGameState(difficulty: this.difficulty, matrix: this.matrix);
}

class _MyGameState extends State<MyGame> {
  var difficulty;
  var matrix;
  _MyGameState({this.difficulty, this.matrix});
  int _points = 0;
  int _counter = 100;
  Timer _timer;
  void _startTimer() {
    _counter = 100;
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer.cancel();
    }
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        if (_counter > 0) {
          _counter--;
        } else {
          _timer.cancel();

          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog();
            },
          );
        }
      });
    });
  }

  /*RANDOM COLORS */
  Random random = Random();
  int colorindex = 0;
  void changeIndex() {
    setState(() => colorindex = random.nextInt(Colors.primaries.length));
  }

  Color getrandom = Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)];
  Color selection = Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _startTimer();
    changeIndex();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          title: Text(
            '$difficulty',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 32.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
      backgroundColor: Colors.primaries[colorindex],
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(64, 114, 64, 0),
              child: Column(children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                            elevation: 25.0,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 124,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      '$_counter',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Seconds Left",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                            elevation: 25.0,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 124,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      '$_points',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                                    ),
                                    Text("Score",
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text("Pick this!"),
                            Icon(Icons.play_arrow_outlined),
                            Card(
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: 50,
                                  height: 50,
                                ),
                                color: getrandom)
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  elevation: 25.0,
                )
              ]),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(48, 26, 48, 52),
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  ),
                  elevation: 25.0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Center(
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: matrix,
                          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                        ),
                        itemCount: matrix * matrix,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              if (selection == getrandom) {
                                HapticFeedback.vibrate();
                                _points++;
                                changeIndex(); // 1) It does not change colors on tap
                              }
                            },
                            child: Card(
                              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                              child: Container(
                                color: selection, // 2) Not initialized randomly
                                //P.S: If I use Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)]
                                //instead of selection. It works but conflicts with timer, changes every seconds
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to...

1. Do not call `setState(...)` in `initState()`.
2. Randomize each grid color. Refer to `_gridColors`.
3. Randomize color of the answer every correct answer. Refer to `_answer`.
4. Separate countdown widget. Refer to `CountdownCard`.

Sample...

```
class MyGame extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyGame({
    required this.difficulty,
    required this.matrix,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String difficulty;
  final int matrix;

  @override
  _MyGameState createState() => _MyGameState();
}

class _MyGameState extends State<MyGame> {
  final List<Color> _gridColors = <Color>[];
  final Random _random = Random();

  late Color _answer;

  int _points = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initColors();
  }

  ///
  void _initColors() {
    _gridColors.clear();
    _answer = _randomColor;
    _gridColors.add(_answer);

    while (_gridColors.length < widget.matrix * widget.matrix) {
      final Color gridColor = _randomColor;

      if (!_gridColors.contains(gridColor)) {
        _gridColors.add(gridColor);
      }
    }

    _gridColors.shuffle();
  }

  ///
  void _changeIndex() => setState(_initColors);

  ///
  Color get _randomColor =>
      Colors.primaries[_random.nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: _answer,
      appBar: _buildAppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(64, 114, 64, 0),
              child: Column(children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                        elevation: 25.0,
                        child: CountdownCard(() {
                          showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog();
                            },
                          );
                        }),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                        elevation: 25.0,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: 124,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  _points.toString(),
                                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                                ),
                                const Text(
                                  "Score",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            const Text("Pick this!"),
                            const Icon(Icons.play_arrow_outlined),
                            Card(
                              child: const SizedBox(
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                              ),
                              color: _answer,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  elevation: 25.0,
                ),
              ]),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(48, 26, 48, 52),
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  ),
                  elevation: 25.0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Center(
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: widget.matrix,
                          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                        ),
                        itemCount: _gridColors.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              if (_gridColors[index] == _answer) {
                                HapticFeedback.vibrate();
                                _points++;
                                _changeIndex();
                              }
                            },
                            child: Card(
                              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                              child: Container(
                                color: _gridColors[index],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  ///
  AppBar _buildAppBar() => AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text(
          widget.difficulty,
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 32.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      );
}

class CountdownCard extends StatefulWidget {
  CountdownCard(this.onTime);

  final VoidCallback onTime;

  @override
  _CountdownCardState createState() => _CountdownCardState();
}

class _CountdownCardState extends State<CountdownCard> {
  late Timer _timer;
  late int _counter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _startTimer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 124,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              _counter.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
            ),
            const Text(
              'Seconds Left',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  ///
  void _startTimer() {
    _counter = 100;

    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      (Timer timer) {
        if (_counter > 0) {
          setState(() => _counter--);
          return;
        }

        _timer.cancel();
        widget.onTime();
      },
    );
  }
}
```